# Path tracing rules for nonlinear relationships

Tags: causality, structural-equation-modeling, causal-diagram

I'm learning about Wright's [path-tracing rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_analysis_(statistics)), and because they deal with covariances it seems like they make the assumption that relationships between variables are linear. If we have nonlinear relationships between variables, can we still use these path-tracing rules to help us determine which variables are good and bad controls?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "nonlinear" (in variables or parameters?).  Products of variables have an extended method: https://doi.org/10.1080/10705511.2022.2141749  This recent work on Trek rules might be relevant: https://doi.org/10.1007/s11336-022-09891-5